# MYSQL does not start after upgrading from version 5.5 to 5.7 on the Centos 6 server

Tags: mysql, centos6

I am upgrading Mysql 5.5 to MYSQL 5.7 on the Centos 6 server, but after upgrading the server does not start. I performed the MYSQL 5.5 version removal process to perform upgrade as indicated on various forums. I will deregulate the step-by-step of the entire process with screen capture, to facilitate the identification of possible errors.

1 - I downloaded the repo for E6 11.

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
```

2 - I did the local installation

```
yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
```

3 - I removed all previous packages, compared to MySQL 5.7

```
yum remove mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch 
yum remove compat-mysql51-5.1.73-1.el6.remi.x86_64
yum remove mysql-libs-5.5.57-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

*I do not know if I made a mistake here when removing MYSQL. This may be preventing MYSQL from starting now.*

4 - I installed MYSQL 5.7

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

Restart MYSQL server 5.7

```
service mysqld restart
```

service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld: [OK]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld: [FAILED]

**To try to solve the problem I tried the following procedures**

```
 df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_srvti02-lv_root
                       31G   18G   12G  60% /
tmpfs                 939M     0  939M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M  162M  290M  36% /boot
```

Check the output of my RPM

```
 rpm -qa | grep mysql

mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch
mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-common-5.7.19-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el6.x86_64
```

Now I don't know what to try to fix this error.

Comment: Please use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. (and most importantly, it allows me to also use cut-and-paste when answering :-) )

Comment: Can you please let me know at what stage is the restart failing? (bash -x /etc/init.d/mysql-community-server restart) Please provide errors you got in mysql logs as well. It will help to understand the problem further.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems that you have managed to also install a CentOS/RHEL 7 package, the mysql57-community-release-**el7**-7.noarch

You should probably check what that package contains and probably need to remove that before `yum update mysql*` will work.

[image: rhel-7 package installed]

Comment: Friend! I was able to install MYSQL by removing the previous version. Now I have another problem, so I updated my question. Would you help me?